# Способы передачи данных между страницами JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Есть страница с скриптом, мне нужно передать значение из этого скрипта в другой скрипт на другой странице которую я открою следом за текущей страницы, как это можно осуществить?

Выглядеть это будет следующим образом, на текущей странице есть комбо-бох и кнопка открыть страницу, по клике на кнопку необходимо открыть заранее написанную страницу с скриптом и передать параметры из комбо-бокса в скрипт на открытой странице. Так же с этим значением (из комбо-бокса) параллельно нужно передавать значение переменных между скриптами. Как это правильно можно осуществить?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ну есть куки, есть локальное хранилище, как уже было сказано. Так же можно использовать массив GET(в адресной строке).

Если все же реально то в некоторых случаях лучше в куки хранить ключ а в базе сохранить нужные данные.

Добавление данных в GET массив:

```
<a href="index.html?data1=0&data2=1">Ссылка</a>
```

Считывание GET массива с помощью JavaScript:

```
var tmp = new Array();      // два вспомагательных
var tmp2 = new Array();     // массива
var param = new Array();

var get = location.search;  // строка GET запроса, то есть все данные после ?
if(get != '') {
    tmp = (get.substr(1)).split('&');   // разделяем переменные
    for(var i=0; i < tmp.length; i++) {
        tmp2 = tmp[i].split('=');       // массив param будет содержать
        param[tmp2[0]] = tmp2[1];       // пары ключ(имя переменной)->значение
    }
    var obj = document.getElementById('greq');  // вывод на экран
    for (var key in param) {
        obj.innerHTML += key+" = "+param[key]+"<br>";
    } 
}
```

Comment: если не трудно подскажите как из javascript работать с GET массивом или направьте ссылкой на нужный ресурс.

Comment: @perfect, если я не ошибаюсь то на чистом JS с ним работать очень неприятно. Нужно доставать все содержимое адресной строки и находить в нем элементы массива. Сейчас найду пример и обновлю ответ.

Comment: все понятно. спасибо. пометьте ваш способ (отделите от основного ответа) чтоб понятней было

Comment: у вас основной ответ идет, а следом ответ на мой комментарий, все слилось. просто перед кодом напишите что это GET способ. для людей кто комментарии не читают. а то сейчас минусов нахватаете за неразбериху в ответе

Comment: в данном случае нет смысла делать `param` массивом. Это обычный объект. Кроме того нет смысла инициализировать переменные массивами, если они потом сразу переписываются

Answer (score 3):

Через куку либо localstorage, если не хочешь хранить инфу на сервере

Еще вариант https://github.com/allmarkedup/purl