# Передача значения по ссылке

Tags: php, javascript, html, ссылки

Допустим, на сайте есть 4 страницы:

- `page.html` (здесь 2 ссылки`<a>`, которые ведут на другую страницу - example.html)
- `example.html` (пустая страница)
- `result1.html`
- `result2.html`

Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на первую ссылку, открывалась страница `example.html` с содержимым `result1.html`? Соответственно, при нажатии на вторую ссылку, также открывается `example.html`, но в неё подгружается содержимое `result2.html`.

Насколько я понимаю, по ссылке необходимо передавать некоторое значение, а на пустой странице делать проверку: если значение одно, то показываем содержимое `result1.html`, если другое - то `result2.html`. Подскажите, как можно осуществить подобное и с помощью чего (JS, PHP или стандартными средствами HTML)?

Заранее огромное спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ну если только подсказать, а не код писать то расcкажу про JS варианты:

**A вариант:**

1 - при наведение курсора на необходимую ссылку (событие onmousemove) записать в куку(coockies) сделать то то (это зависит от той ссылки над которой сейчас курсор)

2 - в коде example.html на событие onload или в самом начале страницы повешать код который прочитает куку и в зависимости от того что там написано выполняет необходимое действие

**B вариант**

1 - В нужной ссылке в параметр href кроме самой ссылке добавить GET параметры

2 - .. и ловить их в example.html и в зависимости от того что в параметрах выполнять соответствующие действия

**C вариант**

использовать локальное хранилище из HTML5 действия будут аналогичны A варианту

PS

а вообще вам следует узнать [способы передачи данных между страницами на JS](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/523526/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-javascript)

Comment: Да, способов море

Comment: Код мне не нужен, я сам хочу понять варианты реализации. Спасибо вам большое, буду "копать" в этих направлениях.

Answer (score 1):

Можно на PHP.

К ссылке на example.php добавьте GET-запрос `example.php?page=1` или `example.php?page=2`

Код в example.php будет примерно такой:

```
<?php
if ($_GET['page'] == 1)
  readfile("result1.html");
if ($_GET['page'] == 2)
  readfile("result2.html");
?>
```